# .NET 4.0 don't use medium trust, does that mean

Tags: .net, nhibernate, reflection

.NET 4.0 don't use medium trust it got a different kind of security, does that mean it's ok to use like NHibernate on hostings that support .NET 4.0? I mean straight out the gate with it no modifications with proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that it doesn't work.